# woocommerce change position of price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

I get this error when trying to render the product price before the main content on the page.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_price_html() on string in /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/price.php:27
```

Here is my code:

```
 //the remove action works fine

remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10);

//this breaks it

add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 40);
```

I assume that because I'm trying to get the price before the main content I need to make sure the global `$product` is loaded.

How would I ensure global `$product` is loaded?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that what you wan't to do is possible. You are moving the rendering of price.php before the loop and outside the add-to-cart form. Then `get_price_html()` need the variable `$price`, not available in here.

To do that, I suppose you need to change in `price.php` template with something like:

```
<?php

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

global $product;
$price = esc_attr( $product->get_price() );
// $price = woocommerce_price( $product->regular_price ); // or this one
// $price = woocommerce_price( $product->sale_price ); // or this one too
?>

<div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">

<p class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></p>

<meta itemprop="price" content="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_price() ); ?>" />
    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="<?php echo esc_attr( get_woocommerce_currency() ); ?>" />
    <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/<?php echo $product->is_in_stock() ? 'InStock' : 'OutOfStock'; ?>" />

</div>
```

Or replace `$product->get_price_html()` by `esc_attr( $product->get_price() );`
You might need to insert the loop inside it too…

Reference: [Overriding Templates via a Theme](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/)

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the code from the single product price template and stick that into your hooked function.
https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/single-product/price.php

```
remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10);

function price_in_title_row() {

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
      exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}
global $product;
?>

<div class="price_in_title_row" itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <h3><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></h3>
    <meta itemprop="price" content="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_display_price() ); ?>" />
    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="<?php echo esc_attr( get_woocommerce_currency() ); ?>" />
    <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/<?php echo $product->is_in_stock() ? 'InStock' : 'OutOfStock'; ?>" />
</div>

}

add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product', 'price_in_title_row', 50);
```